# What happens when a user updates his question on StackOverflow

Tags: support

If a user updates his question with some new trials regarding the code and the respective output achieved then how does this reflect on SO does this question get's posted under new question category or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit a question it bumps it to the top of the home page so that it can get more views - and hopefully an answer.

Basically it's as though you posted a new question.

However, repeated edits to keep the question on the home page are frowned upon and won't be treated well.

Comment: Also, if it is on hold, it will be reviewed for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

The question gets bumped to the front page.

It is not a new question, but simply an edit of the question.